# After first login red null error comes just for a second

Tags: flutter, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, null

When i run the app and log-in / or already logged in before closed app => "Null check operator used on a null value" error pops up and it goes away just in a second. I guess user going to page before data came up.
If i sign-out and log in with another acc. Red screen wont came up but the last users data appears just for a second then current users data comes after. Could you please help me about this.

**My primitiv Sign-in method**

```
Future signIn() async {
try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: emailController.text.trim(),
      password: passwordController.text.trim(),
  );
  print('Signed In');
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  print (e);
  Utils.showSnackBar(e.message);
}}}
```

**User Provider**

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User? _user;
  final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();
  User get getUser => _user!;
  Future<void> refreshUser() async {
    User user = await _authMethods.getUserDetails();
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();}}
```

**The code i use refresh User welcomepage level**

```
class _welcomePageState extends State<welcomePage> {

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    addData();
  }
  addData() async{
    UserProvider _userProvider = Provider.of(context,listen: false);
    await _userProvider.refreshUser();
  }

  @override
```

if that codes not enough to solve i can share all could you please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are force-unwrapping here :
User get getUser => _user!;
which means when you hot-reload the app it is null and the crash appears until it is null, you should make it optional and provide a default value so it doesn't crash.

Comment: I tried but when i make it nullable i cant call any data it gives this error. 
**Property 'email' cannot be accessed on 'User?' because it is potentially null.**
And suggest me to  user!.email  it's both same i guess.

Comment: In that case you can make your user required in the UserProvider so everytime this class is instantiated it will be required, then you can pass it.